# Q&A vs headings format

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception

I am wondering, is there any research or just reasoning over whether a human perceives text easier if it is in questions and answers format or if it is structured with headings and sub-headings.

Questions and answers is close to the natural dialogue communication between two people, which is what we have been accustomed to for ages. One sided communication - text-to-reader is a very recent novelty, evolutionary speaking.

At the same time, I have this obscure gut feeling, that Q&A format, even if combined with headings, does not look "authoritative" enough. I cannot explain why, this is just the way I am feeling it.

The specific occasion for coming up with this whole question is that I am writing a job ad. And I have the feeling that if I use Q&A format, it won't look serious, won't be memorable, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen somewhere that declarative headings in PowerPoint presentations are more effective. From a straight-on cognitive load standpoint, having to decipher a question and pick out the relevant topic words from among all of the different possibilities would certainly increase the extraneous cognitive load required to understand the material. So, my hypothesis is that heading format is better.